Jenkins Unable to save System config changes
My current Jenkins version is 2.346.2 installed on ec2 machine.
I am trying to update now Jenkins to 2.426.3 but using docker container.
i copied all the job data and plugin folder but while updating the  Jenkins URL from system config .
I updated all Jenkins plugins.
I have facing below error & not able to save.
2024-03-14 18:32:45.045+0000 [id=30]    WARNING o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler$Context#log: Error while serving http://jenkins-stag.mgmt.dev.appzen.com/manage/configSubmit
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The frontend sent an unexpected list of classes (["org.jenkins_ci.plugins.any_buildstep.builder.BuilderLister","org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.DefaultBuilderDescriptorLister"]) rather than an expected single class. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/ for more information.
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:750)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate interface org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.BuilderDescriptorLister from {"stapler-class":["org.jenkins_ci.plugins.any_buildstep.builder.BuilderLister","org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.DefaultBuilderDescriptorLister"],"$class":["org.jenkins_ci.plugins.any_buildstep.builder.BuilderLister","org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.DefaultBuilderDescriptorLister"]}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:771)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:551)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:877)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the builderLister parameter of the constructor public org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.singlestep.SingleConditionalBuilder$SingleConditionalBuilderDescriptor(org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.BuilderDescriptorLister)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:879)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:768)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.singlestep.SingleConditionalBuilder$SingleConditionalBuilderDescriptor from {"":"0","builderLister":{"stapler-class":["org.jenkins_ci.plugins.any_buildstep.builder.BuilderLister","org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.DefaultBuilderDescriptorLister"],"$class":["org.jenkins_ci.plugins.any_buildstep.builder.BuilderLister","org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.lister.DefaultBuilderDescriptorLister"]}}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:771)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:551)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:546)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.conditionalbuildstep.singlestep.SingleConditionalBuilder$SingleConditionalBuilderDescriptor.configure(SingleConditionalBuilder.java:146)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.configureDescriptor(Jenkins.java:4097)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:4061)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Please help me to fix the issue
I want how to fix the issue, so I can save the changes done in system config for new version which I am trying to update.

The error message has a link. Have you read that?

@DanielA.White: i see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/views/table-to-div-migration/ in the error. But this changes got updated in version 2.277.2 . And i am currently on jenkins 2.346.2 & trying to update to  2.426.3
